# Python: error on np.where ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm learning Python, I need to rename some files including into a directory. To determine the name, I have an excel file content many information, and some of them will be used.

Excel file:
|...|ID|...|Title

With a path, I create my own dataframe including the list of pdf including into a directory:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display


def ListeFichier(Rep):
    pdf_file = [file for file in os.listdir(Rep) if file.endswith('.pdf')]
    df_f = pd.DataFrame(pdf_file, columns=['FileName'])
    df_f['FileType'] = df_f.FileName.str.rsplit('.', 1).str[-1]
    df_f['File'] = df_f.FileName.str.split('.', 1).str[0]
    print(df_f.dtypes)
    return df_f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    Fichier = filedialog.askopenfile()
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
    df = pd.read_excel(Fichier.name, sheet_name=2,skiprows=range(1,2))
    Repertoire = os.path.dirname(str(Fichier.name))
    FichierRepertoire = pd.DataFrame(ListeFichier(str(Repertoire)))
    header_row = 0
    df.columns = df.iloc[header_row]
    df.set_index('ID', inplace=False)
    FichierRepertoire.set_index('File', inplace=False)
    FichierRepertoire['NewFile'] = np.where(FichierRepertoire['File'] == df['ID'], df['ID'] + ' - '+ df['Title'] + '.pdf', np.nan)
    display(FichierRepertoire)
```

I have written this code and I still have an issue.

> FichierRepertoire['NewFile'] = np.where(**FichierRepertoire['File'] == df['ID']**, df['ID'] + ' - '+ df['Title'] + '.pdf', np.nan)
> I put bold where Python shows me an issue.

The error message is :

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

How can I compare my two dataframe with ID = File and in case there is a matching to give the new name in a new column ?

Thanks in advance,

Bala

Comment: `np.where` is only as good as the arguments, which are evaluated first, before being passed to the function.  So the issue is, how is `FichierRepertoire['File'] == df['ID']` evaluated?  That's comparing 2 Series, apparently with different indices.  `pandas` can only do that if the indices match.  If the Series match in length, and you don't care about indices, you could compare their `numpy` array values. `FichierRepertoire['File'].values == df['ID'].values`

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for your comment. I have change the way to proceed and solve my issue:
`    for index, row in FichierRepertoire.iterrows():
        for saplearning, ligne in df.iterrows():
            if row['File']==ligne['ID']:`
Btw, I have solved my issue. Thank for the support

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by change the way to proceed:

```
        for saplearning, ligne in df.iterrows():
            if row['File']==ligne['ID']:
```

It's working :)

Thanks for all

Philippe